# Image height in bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have database in which I have users profile photo path and other information, I am looping through it using jinja temple and displaying image and other values but image height is varying for each image, how can I fix all image height
My code-

```
<div class="container">
{jinja for loop}
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-2" 
  style="height:60px;">
 <image class="img-fluid" 
 src="some value">
 </div>
 .... 
 </div>
{end loop}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<image class="img-fluid" style="width:100%;height:60px;" src="some value">
```

Comment: Can you also suggest way to reduce image size while maintaining aspect ratio because I am getting blurred image